# How to make a shortest path code in mapbasic?

Tags: mapbasic

I have a column table that consist of 2 points (from / to), i wanted to have a dialog box that will show all possible path from source to destination from a list box and show the shortest path with length value on a different text box.

Any one have tried to code this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Our RouteFinder application can do such calculations, but it is precompiled mapbasic. Or you can use the RW Net library for the same. Find both at http://www.routeware.dk